# How can I include 'react-dom/client' in a Webpack bundle only if it exists (i.e. in react-dom 18+)?

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

I am trying to write code in a library which works with both React 18 and previous versions, so basically

```
const reactMajorVersion = parseInt(ReactDOM.version.split('.')[0], 10);

if (reactMajorVersion >= 18) {
  const ReactDOMClient = require('react-dom/client');
  // use ReactDOMClient.createRoot
} else {
  // use ReactDOM.render
}
```

The problem is that the library needs to work with Webpack (5, in case that matters). So if there is `require('react-dom/client')` in the code, the Webpack parser tries to include it in the bundle, and in previous React versions it fails.

I've attempted as a workaround to do

```
const reactDOMContext = require.context('react-dom', false, /client\.js$/);
const ReactDOMClient = reactDomContext('react-dom/client.js');
```

but this doesn't seem to include the file as expected: if I run with `npx webpack --stats verbose`, I see

```
      modules by path ./node_modules/react-dom/*.js 1.97 KiB
        ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js 1.33 KiB {vendors-node_modules_core-js_modules_es_aggregate-error_js-node_modules_core-js_modules_es_pr-0459f6} [depth 2] [dependent] [built] [code generated]
          [exports: __SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED, createPortal, createRoot, findDOMNode, flushSync, hydrate, hydrateRoot, render, unmountComponentAtNode, unstable_batchedUpdates, unstable_renderSubtreeIntoContainer, version]
          [used exports unknown]
          from origin ./client/app/startup/ClientReduxApp.jsx
            harmony side effect evaluation react-dom [./client/app/startup/ClientReduxApp.jsx] 11:0-33
            harmony import specifier react-dom [./client/app/startup/ClientReduxApp.jsx] 23:33-49
            harmony import specifier react-dom [./client/app/startup/ClientReduxApp.jsx] 23:52-67
          from origin ./client/app/startup/ClientReduxSharedStoreApp.jsx
            harmony side effect evaluation react-dom [./client/app/startup/ClientReduxSharedStoreApp.jsx] 9:0-33
            harmony import specifier react-dom [./client/app/startup/ClientReduxSharedStoreApp.jsx] 18:33-49
            harmony import specifier react-dom [./client/app/startup/ClientReduxSharedStoreApp.jsx] 18:52-67
          from origin ./client/app/startup/ManualRenderAppRenderer.jsx
            harmony side effect evaluation react-dom [./client/app/startup/ManualRenderAppRenderer.jsx] 5:0-33
            harmony import specifier react-dom [./client/app/startup/ManualRenderAppRenderer.jsx] 7:33-49
            harmony import specifier react-dom [./client/app/startup/ManualRenderAppRenderer.jsx] 7:52-67
          from origin ./node_modules/react-redux/es/utils/reactBatchedUpdates.js
            harmony side effect evaluation react-dom [./node_modules/react-redux/es/utils/reactBatchedUpdates.js] 2:0-52
            harmony export imported specifier react-dom [./node_modules/react-redux/es/utils/reactBatchedUpdates.js] 2:0-52
          cjs require react-dom [./node_modules/react-on-rails/node_package/lib/clientStartup.js] 12:34-54
          cjs require react-dom [./node_modules/react-on-rails/node_package/lib/reactHydrateOrRender.js] 7:34-54
        ./node_modules/react-dom/server.browser.js 658 bytes {vendors-node_modules_core-js_modules_es_aggregate-error_js-node_modules_core-js_modules_es_pr-0459f6} [depth 3] [dependent] [built] [code generated]
          [exports: renderToNodeStream, renderToReadableStream, renderToStaticMarkup, renderToStaticNodeStream, renderToString, version]
          [used exports unknown]
          cjs require react-dom/server [./node_modules/react-on-rails/node_package/lib/handleError.js] 7:31-58
          cjs require react-dom/server [./node_modules/react-on-rails/node_package/lib/serverRenderReactComponent.js] 42:31-58
```

and

```
  ../../node_modules/react-dom/ sync nonrecursive client\.js$ [../../node_modules/react-dom sync client\.js$] 160 bytes {server-bundle} [depth 3] [dependent] [built] [code generated]
    [no exports]
    [used exports unknown]
    require.context [./node_modules/react-on-rails/node_package/lib/reactHydrateOrRender.js] 18:30-80
```

(Why is it looking in `../../node_modules` instead of `./node_modules`?)

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
  ReactDOMClient = require('react-dom/client');
} catch (e) {
  // do nothing
}
```

will [only warn about missing module](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/339#issuecomment-47739112) under React 16, not error. It would be better to avoid even a warning, but I can live with it.